# screen not navigating to other screen based on conditions, on button click

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-button, swiftui-navigation

I want to navigate to ChatScreen() based on conditions, when click on right group, print statement is showing "group found" but its not navigating:

```
List(viewModel.danceGroups) { group in
                    
                    Button(action: {
                            if authViewModel.authenticationState == .authenticated {
                                check(groupId: group.id, userId: authViewModel.uid){ performed in
                                    if performed{
                                        goToChatScreen = true
                                    }else {
                                        showPopup = true
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                showSignInSheet = true
                            }
                        }) {
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                    Text(group.groupName)
                                        .bold()
                                        .font(.title2)
                                    Text(hoursAgo(from: TimeInterval(group.timestamp), from: group.isPermanent))
                                        .font(.footnote)
                                        .italic()
                            }
                        }
                        .navigationDestination(isPresented: $goToChatScreen){
                            ChatScreen(groupId: group.id)
                        }
                }


func check(groupId: String, userId: String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        let database = Database.database().reference()
        
        let GroupsRef = //path
        
        GroupsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
            if snapshot.exists() {
                
                if let joinedDanceGroups = snapshot.value as? [String: Bool], joinedDanceGroups[groupId] == true {
                    print("group found")
                    completion(true)
                } else {
                    print("group not found")
                    completion(false)
                }
            } else {
                completion(false)
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to first assign the a bool according to check() and then checking conditions for navigation or popup but then it shows popup even when clicking right group

Comment: You need a `NavigationStack` to be able to use `navigationDestination(...)`. Also you need to put 
 the `navigationDestination` **outside** the `List`.
 Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you very much, I needed to put navigationDestination outside the List.